# Solving the Airy equation by Borel summation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, connections

The Airy equation is the canonical example of the Stokes phenomenon but, as of yet, I've not seen it being solved by Borel summation (which is the main way to explicitly construct examples of Stokes phenomena).

The Airy equation is
$$f''(z)\ + \ zf(z)\ =\ 0$$
which (using the basis $f(z),f'(z)$) is a flat section  the following connection on the trivial bundle on $\mathbf{C}^\times$:
$$\nabla\ =\ d\ +\ \begin{pmatrix} & -1\\ z&\end{pmatrix}dz\ =\ d\ +\ \begin{pmatrix} & -w^{-2}\\ -w^{-3}&\end{pmatrix}dz$$
Here $w=z^{-1}$. At $w=0$  it has an irregular singularity.

The standard way to solve this is to pick a formal gauge transformation $F\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbf{C}[[w]])$ which transforms e.g.
$$F\cdot \nabla\ =\ d\ +\ D(z)dz$$
where $D(z)$ is diagonal, then $Fe^{\int D(z)dz}$ is a formal solution which can be Borel summed to an actual solution on sectors. Of course in the Airy case maybe the normal form is something other than $d+\text{diagonal}$.

> **Question.** Is it possible to solve the Airy equation in this way?

---

P.S. of course there are more direct ways to solve the Airy equation, in asking this question I'm more looking for an honest example of the Borel summation technique, which is always presented rather non-explicitly in texts.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually written in most books which deal with Airy's equation, but without mentioning the fancy name "Borel summation", since the method is much older than that. They simply make the Laplace transform of the Airy equation,
and obtain the algebraic equation which can be explicitly solved. This gives an integral representation of the Airy function as the inverse Laplace transform (=Borel transform) of an explicit function.